# Getting data to correct computer

Tags: networking, router

So I have taken some networking classes and there is still something that I do not understand thoroughly.

How does google (or any external web server of any kind) get data back to the right computer? And to be more specific, imagine this scenario:

I have a network which accesses the internet on IP 27.52.35.86 and within this network I have a linksys router and 4 computers

- 192.168.1.100 (I'll call this 100)
- 192.168.1.102 (102)
- 192.168.1.103 (103)
- 192.168.1.105 (105)

Say that 100 hits http://www.google.com/ It will make an HTTP request for data. If I recall correclty from my classes, the MAC address is only sent between mid-points. Google does not know 100's MAC address, nor does 100 know Google's MAC address. Google just knows to respond to 27.52.35.86, so how does that HTTP Request get to 192.168.1.100 without 102, 103, and 105 seeing it?

Does each request have a unique ID or something of the sort so that the router can know who to forward it on to? Or is it something more simple or complex than that?